# Loading and displaying externally hosted SWF into an Adobe Air application

Tags: actionscript-3, security, air

I have a game written in AS3 on top of Adobe AIR. Now that I've found a publisher for the game, I need to load an external swf to display advertisements (cpmstar). Unfortunately it hasn't been straightforward, and I can't seem to get any advertisements to display on the stage. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Here's my code:

```
Security.allowDomain("server.cpmstar.com");

var cpmstarViewSWFUrl:String = "http://server.cpmstar.com/adviewas3.swf";

var cpmstarLoader:Loader = new Loader();

var allowSWF:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext( false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null );
allowSWF.allowCodeImport = true;

var urlRequest:URLRequest =  new URLRequest(cpmstarViewSWFUrl + "?contentspotid="+ < my ID > );

cpmstarLoader.load( urlRequest, allowSWF );
addChild( cpmstarLoader );
```

With the above, I see the url request successfully complete ( I can also see the `200` success response in Chrome ) , but I never see any content added to my stage. I've also tried, with no success, loading the distant URL with `URLLoader` and then reloading it through `loadByte` as described here: [AIR Loading server hosted swf into same sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043716/air-loading-server-hosted-swf-into-same-sandbox)

If the code above looks okay, could the advertisers `swf` file be doing something that isn't allowing it to play nicely with this code? If so, what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I opened your swf URL in a browser and it was blank ! May be you'v forgot some params or something ... in all cases, if you can see nothing in the browser, sure you will see nothing in your AIR app !

Comment: Yes, I was curious about that too.  I am concatenating a special unique identifier in the actual URL request: `new URLRequest(cpmstarViewSWFUrl + "?contentspotid="+ < my ID > )`, but even with it, I still see nothing in the browser.

Comment: FWIW I've reached out to CPMStar separately in hopes they can give me some insight with respect to the blank pages.